# Problem updating html check box in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, html

Here's my code, I don't know why the checkbox isnt updated when I try to update the mysql database. Only the input box are being updated.

```
   <tr>
<td><font size="3"></td>
<td></td>
<input type='hidden' name="stats6" value="0">
<td><input name="stats6" type="checkbox" id="dep" value="<?php echo $row["STAT6"]; ?>" <?php echo $row["STAT6"] ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> >Dependent</td>
<td><font size="3"></td>
<td></td>
<input type='hidden' name="stats7" value="0">
<td><input name="stats7" type="checkbox" id="emp" value="<?php echo $row["STAT7"]; ?>" <?php echo $row["STAT7"] ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> >Employee</td>
<td><font size="3"></td>
<td></td>
<input type='hidden' name="stats8" value="0">
<td><input name="stats8" type="text" id="" value="<?php echo $row["STAT8"]; ?>" maxlength="15">Others</td>
```

And here's the form action:

```
mysql_select_db("Hospital", $con);

mysql_query("UPDATE t2 SET HOSPNUM ='$_POST[hnum]', ROOMNUM='$_POST[rnum]', ADATE='$_POST[adate]',  ADTIME='$_POST[adtime]', LASTNAME='$_POST[lname]', FIRSTNAME='$_POST[fname]', MIDNAME='$_POST[mname]', CSTAT='$_POST[cs]', AGE='$_POST[age]', BDAY='$_POST[bday]', ADDRESS='$_POST[ad]', SEX='$_POST[sex]', 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     STAT='$_POST[stats1]', STAT2='$_POST[stats2]', STAT3='$_POST[stats3]', STAT4='$_POST[stats4]', STAT5='$_POST[stats5]', STAT6='$_POST[stats6]', STAT7='$_POST[stats7]', STAT8='$_POST[stats8]', NURSE='$_POST[nurse]'              
WHERE PNUM ='$_POST[pnum]'");
```

what might be wrong with my code?It doesn't really update the data that are in the checkbox. And when I try to search it, its all zeros

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a number of problems. Here are some of the key ones:

- Your HTML is invalid. You have `<input>` elements **between** table cells. Use a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/).
- You have multiple inputs with the same name (`<input type='hidden' name="stats6" value="0">` and `<input name="stats6" type="checkbox"` for instance) and:

  - You are looking for a single element of that name in your PHP
  - You are naming them without `[]` on the end (which is only a problem in PHP)

PHP, IIRC, populates an $_POST['foo'] with the value of the first 'foo' it encounters.

It looks like you are trying to have a default value in case the checkbox isn't there. If so, handle that entirely with PHP. Don't add hidden inputs to the form.

- You are dumping form data directly into the database without any sanity checking whatsoever, thus creating a **massive** [sql injection vulnerability](http://bobby-tables.com/) (see the [php fixes](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html)).

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the hidden input for each checkbox need to be behind the tag for it. I don't remember how PHP do with duplicates, but that might be the problem.

But, another note. 
I hope that code is only for example, you should **never** put data directly into the database from the input without sanitizing and validating it beforehand. Doing it like that will open up the possibilities for SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's recommended to use $_POST["hnum"] instead of $_POST[hnum]. Guess it is a typo.

ow the real problem. Checkbox values are only set when they are checked. If they are not checked, there will be no value like $_POST["hnum"]. Maybe that's part of your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Your Html is correct the problem is with your SQL

i just have made come corrections to your query try it,

```
$sql = "UPDATE t2 SET ";
$sql .= "HOSPNUM ='".$_POST['hnum']."', ";
$sql .= "ROOMNUM    ='".$_POST['rnum']."', ";
$sql .= "ADATE      ='".$_POST['adate']."', ";
$sql .= "ADTIME     ='".$_POST['adtime']."', ";
$sql .= "LASTNAME   ='".$_POST['lname']."', ";
$sql .= "FIRSTNAME  ='".$_POST['fname']."', ";
$sql .= "MIDNAME    ='".$_POST['mname']."', ";
$sql .= "CSTAT      ='".$_POST['cs']."', ";
$sql .= "AGE        ='".$_POST['age']."', ";
$sql .= "BDAY       ='".$_POST['bday']."', ";
$sql .= "ADDRESS    ='".$_POST['ad']."', ";
$sql .= "SEX        ='".$_POST['sex']."', ";
$sql .= "STAT       ='".$_POST['stats1']."', ";
$sql .= "STAT2      ='".$_POST['stats2']."', ";
$sql .= "STAT3      ='".$_POST['stats3']."', ";
$sql .= "STAT4      ='".$_POST['stats4']."', ";
$sql .= "STAT5      ='".$_POST['stats5']."', ";
$sql .= "STAT6      ='".$_POST['stats6']."', ";
$sql .= "STAT7      ='".$_POST['stats7']."', ";
$sql .= "STAT8      ='".$_POST['stats8']."', ";
$sql .= "NURSE      ='".$_POST['nurse']."'";
$sql .= "WHERE PNUM ='".$_POST['pnum']."'";

mysql_query($sql);
```

you have forget to put the "'" in the post values

fore example you have  `$_POST[stats1]` which should be `$_POST['stats1']`

have a try

Comment: The HTML isn't correct, and your SQL has major SQL injection vulnerabilities.